# Forecasting with ETS yields unexpected constant value

Tags: r, forecasting

I would like to do a forecast from a series of 15 datapoints (I know the sample is very small)

The list of data:

```
acper <- c(0.17437418,0.157034518,0.156229944,0.165366982,0.17212133,0.205634804,0.177709816,0.162522795,0.165439735,0.147619365,0.144451531,0.151751211,0.129296274,0.129692449,0.118168555)
```

now i wanted to do a forecast with ets

```
ets.model <- ets(acper)
forecast(ets.model, h=3)
plot(forecast(ets.model, h=3))
```

and i get the same forecast for all following years

```
Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
16      0.1181686 0.09764478 0.1386923 0.08678015 0.1495570
17      0.1181686 0.08914355 0.1471936 0.07377865 0.1625585
18      0.1181686 0.08262033 0.1537168 0.06380224 0.1725349
19      0.1181686 0.07712100 0.1592161 0.05539174 0.1809454
20      0.1181686 0.07227600 0.1640611 0.04798195 0.1883552
21      0.1181686 0.06789578 0.1684413 0.04128298 0.1950541
22      0.1181686 0.06386775 0.1724694 0.03512264 0.2012145
23      0.1181686 0.06011855 0.1762186 0.02938874 0.2069484
24      0.1181686 0.05659723 0.1797399 0.02400334 0.2123338
25      0.1181686 0.05326668 0.1830704 0.01890970 0.2174274
```

Why do I always get 0.1181686? this doesn't seem valid to me.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the following link: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293303/forecasting-values-are-coming-same-in-r). For experimental purposes, i would suggest storing randomly generated values in `acper` and checking if it generates different values.

Comment: It is correct, the best estimate has no trend or seasonal component. Use for example `ets(acper,  model = "ZAN")` to add trend, if you believe there is one .

Comment: When i use the "ZAN" model, I also get the very same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform to `ts` first:

```
library(forecast)

acper <- c (0.17437418,0.157034518,0.156229944,0.165366982,0.17212133,0.205634804,0.177709816,0.162522795,0.165439735,0.147619365,0.144451531,0.151751211,0.129296274,0.129692449,0.118168555)

ets.model <- ets(ts(acper, start = c(2000, 1), freq = 12), model = "ZAN")
forecast(ets.model, h=3)
#Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
#Apr 2001      0.1261377 0.10238661 0.1498888 0.08981353 0.1624619
#May 2001      0.1227179 0.09840193 0.1470338 0.08552986 0.1599059
#Jun 2001      0.1192980 0.09442959 0.1441664 0.08126504 0.1573310
plot(forecast(ets.model, h=3))
```

Comment: thank you. In case of other models (e.g. ARIMA or BATS) this transformation doesnt yield other results - what would be a good way to choose the best fitting model? maybe AIC? but in case of BATS AIC is not applicable.. thank you and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Exponential smoothing gives greater weights to more recent samples and less to older, whereas a moving average (ARIMA model in R) will give equal weights to all observations (this may suit your sample better). Due to the fact, your sample is so small, it seems to have just taken the last value and rounded upward.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Also the ARIMA yields in the very same value for the following years. Would it be an idea to do maybe a spline forecast? I mean... but why isnt it possible to generate an ARIMA forecast out of 15 points? it shouldt be always the same value

Comment: The fact that alpha is almost one has nothing to do with the flat forecast.